# Resolving @PropertySource placeholder springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I have a code that has `@PropertySource` with placeholder:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ DataSourceConfig.class })
@PropertySource(value = "event-sql-${placeholder:oracle}.xml")
public class AuditEventRepositoryConfig {
```

I want to use `{placeholder}` to load different xml such as `event-sql-azure.xml`. How do I achieve this?

EDIT: I found https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE_to_4.2.0.RC1/Spring%20Framework%204.2.0.RC1/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

stating that:

```
Any ${...} placeholders present in a @PropertySource resource location will be resolved against the set of property sources already registered against the environment.
```

However, I am not sure what it means by **set of property sources already registered against the environment.**

Comment: The doc further says: "e.g. system properties or environment variables", but can also be: (already registered) alternative property sources/...imported configs... application./bootstrap...properties

Comment: @xerx593 so do you mean if I have property defined in application.properties, it would work?

Comment: Yup, I assumed so (since spring *is* clever and registers application (and other default) properties quite early (but with low precedence, so they still can be overwritten)), ... and now have  confirmed it experimentally :)

Comment: hmm.. I believe I tried it but it didn't work out.

Comment: let the believe to religion, bro: here is a [github](https://github.com/xerx593/soq63689900) with spring-boot 2.3.3

Comment: oh im stupid. this works. I was testing with my Test class and I obviously had to add it to test.properties.. Thanks!